# Remove an already selected option from an rshiny dashboard sidebar menu

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an r shiny dashboard which allows me to compare data when 2 NBA teams play each other. The following is my dashboardSidebar which allows me to pick the 2 teams. As it is the second menu simply defaults to the second item in sort(unique(season$team)), which is the list of teams. I would like to make such that the whatever team is selected as team1 is simply removed from being an option for team2. How can I do this?

```
  dashboardSidebar(selectInput("team1", "Team 1:", sort(unique(season$team))),         
                   selectInput("team2", "Team 2:",
                   sort(unique(season$team)),selected = sort(unique(season$team))[2]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use updateSelectInput. As I have no access to your data frame I used the iris data frame. Change iris for your data frame.

Put this in your UI

```
selectInput("team1", "Team 1:", sort(unique(iris$Species))),
selectInput("team2", "Team 1:", "")
```

And put this in your Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {


  outVar = reactive({
     df = iris[iris$Species != input$team1,]
     df$Species
  })
   observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, "team2",
        choices = outVar()
    )})
}
```